# List of momentum indicators

Tags: indicator, momentum

Is there a definite list of momentum indicators? [A quick search on Google did not yield much](https://www.google.com/search?q=list%20of%20momentum%20indicators&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), so I thought to ask this here.

Comment: if no one posts one I can start a list here with the common ones.

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful it would be great if you could accept it - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 5):

The following paper gives you a range of different indicators and methods and, even better, unifies the whole concept:

[Which Trend Is Your Friend?](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2603731)
by Levine, A., Pedersen, L.

**Abstract**

> Managed-futures funds (sometimes called CTAs) trade predominantly on
>   trends. There are several ways of identifying trends, either using
>   heuristics or statistical measures often called “filters.” Two
>   important statistical measures of price trends are time series
>   momentum and moving average crossovers. We show both empirically and
>   theoretically that these trend indicators are closely connected. In
>   fact, they are equivalent representations in their most general forms,
>   and they also capture many other types of filters such as the HP
>   filter, the Kalman filter, and all other linear filters. Further, we
>   show how trend filters can be equivalently represented as functions of
>   past prices vs. past returns. Our results unify and broaden a range of
>   trend-following strategies and we discuss the implications for
>   investors.

Answer (score 4):

I think, the following list answers your question. Even  though the below list is exhaustive, there might be some recent changes. Try looking for additional sources, you might find some more useful information.

- ADX  Average Directional Movement Index
- ADXR Average Directional   Movement Index Rating
- APO  Absolute Price Oscillator
- AROON    Aroon
- AROONOSC Aroon Oscillator
- BOP  Balance Of Power
- CCI  Commodity Channel    Index
- CMO  Chande Momentum Oscillator
- DX   Directional Movement Index
- MACD Moving Average Convergence/Divergence
- MACDEXT  MACD with    controllable MA type
- MACDFIX  Moving Average Convergence/Divergence Fix 12/26
- MFI  Money Flow Index
- MINUS_DI Minus Directional Indicator
- MINUS_DM Minus Directional Movement
- MOM  Momentum
- PLUS_DI  Plus    Directional Indicator
- PLUS_DM  Plus Directional Movement
- PPO  Percentage Price Oscillator
- ROC  Rate of change :
- ROCP Rate of change Percentage:
- ROCR Rate of change ratio:
- ROCR100  Rate of change ratio 100 scale:
- RSI  Relative Strength Index
- STOCH    Stochastic
- STOCHF   Stochastic Fast
- STOCHRSI Stochastic Relative Strength Index
- TRIX 1-day Rate-Of-Change (ROC) of a Triple Smooth EMA
- ULTOSC   Ultimate Oscillator
- WILLR    Williams' %R
- ASI  Accumulative Swing Index
- ADR  Advance Decline Ratio
- IMI  Intraday Momentum Index

Comment: This answer would be even better if you could add some sources!

Comment: If the information could have been easily found, i hope there wouldn't be this question. I had been collecting information from multiple sources since long. There weren't any direct sources then, so i had been documenting on my own. I have shared the information from the same doc. :)

Comment: Well, the background of my question is to see definitions of all these abbreviations and words you write. Otherwise this information is nearly useless.

Comment: But the question says "Is there a definite list of momentum indicators", so was my answer inline with the question. If you are expecting a definition, please raise a question with the kind of information you seek. Also, the definitions are inline with the abbreviations. I am not quite sure what you are expecting in a single question. The complete explanation for these would exceed 300+ pages (from what i have, including formulas and other explanations).

Comment: Yes, perhaps you are right that this question is not a very good fit for our site. On the other hand: Do you see my point that just giving dozens of abbreviations without giving any references or explanations doesn't really help either?